# Activate and deactivate a trigger in an Oracle script with Begin - End statement

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need to deactivate a trigger before to execute some requests in my script:

```
DECLARE
    CPM_ID PLS_INTEGER;
    CPM_ID_TO_DELETE PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT ID INTO CPM_ID_TO_DELETE FROM CPM_T WHERE TITLE LIKE '%My Contract%';
        DELETE CPM_HIST_T WHERE HIST_ID  = CPM_ID_TO_DELETE;
        -- Deactivate the trigger
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER CPM_HIST_ID_TRIG DISABLE';
        DELETE CPM_T WHERE ID  = CPM_ID_TO_DELETE;
        -- Activate the trigger
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER CPM_HIST_ID_TRIG ENABLE';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
            THEN
                NULL;
    END;
    CPM_ID := CPM_ID_SEQ.nextval;
    Insert into CPM_T (ID,ORG_ID,TITLE) values (CPM_ID,'7257','My Contract');
END;
```

Nevertheless it's not working, I get this error: "Usually a PL/SQL compilation error - ORA-06550"

Apparently I cannot execute the command "ALTER....."

Could you please help me to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

What does "Usually" mean? Sometimes, but not always? Because, code you posted looks OK and doesn't raise errors for my test case.

Sample objects:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE cpm_t
  2  (
  3     id       NUMBER,
  4     org_id   VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     title    VARCHAR2 (20)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE cpm_hist_t
  2  (
  3     hist_id   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cpm_hist_id_trig
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON cpm_hist_t
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     NULL;
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE cpm_id_seq;

Sequence created.
```

Your code (converted to a procedure; I didn't change anything):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test
  2  AS
  3     cpm_id            PLS_INTEGER;
  4     cpm_id_to_delete  PLS_INTEGER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     BEGIN
  7        SELECT id
  8          INTO cpm_id_to_delete
  9          FROM cpm_t
 10         WHERE title LIKE '%My Contract%';
 11
 12        DELETE cpm_hist_t
 13         WHERE hist_id = cpm_id_to_delete;
 14
 15        -- Deactivate the trigger
 16        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER CPM_HIST_ID_TRIG DISABLE';
 17
 18        DELETE cpm_t
 19         WHERE id = cpm_id_to_delete;
 20
 21        -- Activate the trigger
 22        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER CPM_HIST_ID_TRIG ENABLE';
 23     EXCEPTION
 24        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 25        THEN
 26           NULL;
 27     END;
 28
 29     cpm_id := cpm_id_seq.NEXTVAL;
 30
 31     INSERT INTO cpm_t (id, org_id, title)
 32          VALUES (cpm_id, '7257', 'My Contract');
 33  END;
 34  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXEC p_test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM cpm_t;

        ID ORG_ID               TITLE
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 7257                 My Contract

SQL> SELECT * FROM cpm_t;

        ID ORG_ID               TITLE
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         2 7257                 My Contract

SQL>
```

So, nothing wrong here.

Could you post your own SQL*Plus session which illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work (if you are using SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, etc. then you need to add a PL/SQL terminator `/` on a new-line at the end of the PL/SQL block).

You can possibly (depending on what your trigger does) rewrite it as:

```sql
DECLARE
  CPM_ID_TO_DELETE CPM_T.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    -- Deactivate the trigger
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER CPM_HIST_ID_TRIG DISABLE';

    DELETE CPM_T
    WHERE TITLE LIKE '%My Contract%'
    RETURNING ID INTO CPM_ID_TO_DELETE;

    DELETE CPM_HIST_T WHERE HIST_ID  = CPM_ID_TO_DELETE;

    -- Activate the trigger
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER CPM_HIST_ID_TRIG ENABLE';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      NULL;
  END;
  Insert into CPM_T (ID,ORG_ID,TITLE) values (CPM_ID_SEQ.nextval,'7257','My Contract');
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oK--wIPv)